# Uploading a new file revision using Google Drive Api

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a multi-part document using the Google Drive Api. (Specifically - PUT https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{fileId} )

My environment has two super-admins (User A and B) (for whatever reason). 
The Api is authenticated using one of the 'super-admin' (User A).

When I try to upload a revision for User A, then it succeeds.
However, when I try to upload it for User B, I get

'The authenticated user does not have the required access to the file {fileId}'.

I would imagine the super admin to have access to everything. 
Does it entail to the scope I am using ? ( This is my current scope of request - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive)

Can someone tell me what am I missing ? :-/ 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even super admins do not have access to a file unless they've been directly granted access to that file. You can:

1. Have User A share the file with User B (writer access). Then User B can update the file.
2. Authenticate as User A in order to perform the update.
3. [Use a Service Account to authenticate and act as any user in the domain.](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation)

Comment: I like the option 3.
But, I am slightly confused here. Currently, I am using 'Client ID for Web Application' method, wherein the super admin grants me (the developer), access to the drive. ( The process where super admin has to login to his account and explicitly grant access and then, control is redirected to my application). 
I then use the 'access token' to make the requests. 
I configured the service account but, I don't think the above workflow (where super admin grants me access), is possible with Service Accounts (as there is no concept of redirect uri with a service account).

Comment: having access to the super admin account is not sufficient. You need a service account that has been delegated rights to act on behalf of users in the domain for the desired scopes. See the link I included in #3, it lists out the steps in detail.

Comment: Thanks, Jay. 
I see - quoted from the 3rd link - 
/**
 * Build and returns a Drive service object authorized with the service accounts
 * that act on behalf of the given user.
 *
 * @param userEmail The email of the user.

Can this 'userEmail' be SuperAdmin, or does it have to be the user who is the owner of the file ? 
I want to be able to modify the data for all the users in the enterprise.

Comment: It can be any user in the domain but for your case, it needs to be the owner of the file. You've given the service account delegate access to your domain so the delegate account can become any user by changing the value of userEmail. However, the same file permissions apply. You won't be able to access files not owned or shared to the user you specify.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried it however, this approach is going to scale for us - since, it would entail requesting a credential for each user (where there can be thousands' of them). 
Instead, I was thinking to try and probably 
i) update the file permissions via the original OAuth access token - but, even that would be forbidden right ?

Comment: I meant _not going to scale for us_ :)